Converting NC into text
I'm struggling to understand how to convert a NetCDF into a CSV or plain text, where I can see the specific values of its variables. The NetCDF documentation recommends a NC to CSV converter, but using that makes the file unreadable (mess like D¢FS6o–]nŸÒãÉt®hU¥ )HA). The solutions provided using command line are a little beyond my understanding, is that the only option?

this is almost certainly not the route you want to go down as the exported files will be huge
